# How to remove all the element which equal to certain value in POJO classes?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, model, pojo

I have a Pojo class like this:

```
public class Item
{
  private int id;
  private String username;

//here all getter and setter 
}
```

Here is the sample of my sample from server:

```
{
"id" : 2
"name" : "Ali"

"id" : 3
"name" : "janice"

"id" : 2
"name" : "Ali"

"id" : 5
"name" : "tupac"

"id" : 2
"name" : "Ali"

"id" : 8
"name" : "William"

"id" : 2
"name" : "Ali"  
}
```

What I want to do is remove all the element inside the sample above,which the `id == 2`,so it will left element with `id==3,5 and 8`.

I can remove 1 element with the method below:

```
List<MyArrayList> myArrayList;

for(int i =0;i < myarraylist.size();i++){
        if(myarraylist.get(i).getId() == 2){
            myarraylist.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

But I cant remove all the element which `id==2` in one time.Somebody please give me a solution to do this..

My question is,how can I remove all 4 element which is `id==2` in the sample above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**POJO CLASS**

```
    public class Item {

    private int id;
    private String username;


    public Item(int id, String username) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (obj instanceof Item) {
            Item temp = (Item) obj;
            if (this.id == temp.id)
                return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return (this.id.hashCode() + this.username.hashCode());
    }
}
```

**ACTIVITY CODE**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        arrayList.clear();

        Item item = new Item(1, "UserName 1");

        arrayList.add(item);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Item item2 = new Item(2, "UserName 2");
            arrayList.add(item2);

        }

        Item item3 = new Item(3, "UserName 3");
        arrayList.add(item3);


        Item item4 = new Item(4, "UserName4");
        arrayList.add(item4);

        Item item5 = new Item(5, "UserName 5");
        arrayList.add(item5);


        Set<Item> s = new HashSet<Item>();
        s.addAll(arrayList);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        arrayList.addAll(s);

        for (int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
            if (arrayList.get(i).getId() == 2) {
                arrayList.remove(i);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("ID      :", arrayList.get(i).getId() + "");
            Log.e("UserName:", arrayList.get(i).getUsername() + "");
        }
    }


}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
04-21 16:56:40.114 com.example.nilesh.testapp E/ID      :: 1
04-21 16:56:40.114 com.example.nilesh.testapp E/UserName:: UserName 1
04-21 16:56:40.114 com.example.nilesh.testapp E/ID      :: 5
04-21 16:56:40.114 com.example.nilesh.testapp E/UserName:: UserName 5
04-21 16:56:40.114 com.example.nilesh.testapp E/ID      :: 4
04-21 16:56:40.114 com.example.nilesh.testapp E/UserName:: UserName4
04-21 16:56:40.114 com.example.nilesh.testapp E/ID      :: 3
04-21 16:56:40.114 com.example.nilesh.testapp E/UserName:: UserName 3
```

Comment: hey bro,as you can see,it have 4 element with `id==2` in the arraylist..how can I remove all that 4 in 1 time? Cause your answer look like only remove 1 element,which is 10..

Comment: @ken you want to remove all item which id is 2 right

Comment: yup..thats is correct..so the the array just left 3,5,8.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyArrayList> myArrayList;

//take new List
List<MyArrayList> newList = new Arraylist<>();

for(int i =0;i < myarraylist.size();i++){
        //id not matched
        if(myarraylist.get(i).getId() != 2){
            add to new list
            newList.add(i);

        }
    }
```